# Listening for a boolean change with Javascript/jquery (Proxy object)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

Javascript Proxy not triggering. I am triying to trigger some functionality after 10 seconds. But after 10 seconds, when I update the variable "dezSecondsNaPagina" nothing happens.

```
var dezSegundosNaPagina = new Object();
dezSegundosNaPagina.valor = false;

var targetProxy = new Proxy(dezSegundosNaPagina, {
  set: function(target, key, value) {
    target[key] = value;

    if (dezSegundosNaPagina.valor) {
      console.log("aumentar visualização");
    }
    return true;
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    dezSegundosNaPagina.valor = true;
    alert(dezSegundosNaPagina.valor);
  }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `targetProxy.valor = true;` in setTimeout method.

```js
var dezSegundosNaPagina = new Object();
dezSegundosNaPagina.valor = false;

var targetProxy = new Proxy(dezSegundosNaPagina, {
  set: function(target, key, value) {
    target[key] = value;

    if (dezSegundosNaPagina.valor) {
      console.log("aumentar visualização");
    }
    return true;
  }
});


  setTimeout(function() {
    targetProxy.valor = true;
    alert(dezSegundosNaPagina.valor);
  }, 3000);
```

Comment: A checked the snipped several minutes and that one passed by me.